# late 80's fiction book about doctor experimenting on pregnant woman and the kids later abilities

Tags: identification-request

It had a holographic cover with lightning, that's why it caught my eye.  The story was a doctor had performed secret genetic experiments on a bunch of pregnant women. The women were under surveillance and later the kids were abducted for further testing as they developed powers.  I think it was called children of the light, or something similar. I remember the awesome cover, and the general story line and would really like to read it again.

Answer (score 3):

*[Hear the Children Calling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1887039.Hear_the_Children_Calling)* by Clare McNally comes up in similar searches on goodreads.com: [here](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19353897-solved-adult-novel-that-deals-with-children-who-were-kidnapped-and-expe) and [here](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22524250-solved-1980s-teen-fiction-about-abducted-children-and-a-laboratory-s), for example.
[image: cover image]